# Не могу получить класс, получается только через консоль

Tags: javascript, iframe, vimeo

Всем привет.

У меня проблемка, есть блок и  в нем есть iframe (видео, VIMEO). Я не могу достать любой класс с iframe-а для манипуляции с ним.

Я пытаюсь его получить, но он возвращает пустую коллекцию. Если в консоли прописать var vimTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('vp-title');, то будет пусто HTMLCollection []

А если сделать тоже самое, НО  уже vp-title скопировать с дерева DOM (выделить класс => Ctrl+c => Ctrl+V)
var q = document.getElementsByClassName(' vp-title ');  То я получу то что хочу и могу управлять HTMLCollection [div.vp-title.invisible.hidden], в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) вы не можете взаимодействовать с содержимым `iframe`, взятым с другого домена. Если `src` ведёт на ваш домен, то получить доступ к `iframe` можно следующими способами:

JQuery

```
$("iframe").contents()
```

JS

```
let iframe=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0],
iframeContent=iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow.document
```

Comment: То есть мне надо получить конкретный фрейм, прописать один из этих способов и у меня будет доступ к стилизации?

Comment: Я хотел к вам обратиться @Diskyp

Comment: @МишаПодлевских нет, это значит, что если у вас сайт equestria.com и вы используете `<iframe src="vimeo.com">`? то вы не сможете взаимодействовать с этим iframe, вообще никак, ибо его содержимое взято с другого домена, однако если вы используете `<iframe src="equestria.com/pony.jpg">`, то всё ОК, вы можете с ним взаимодействовать при помощи методов, которые я написал.